# How to download and write a file from Github using Requests

Tags: python, github, python-requests

Lets say there's a file that lives at the github repo:

https://github.com/someguy/brilliant/blob/master/somefile.txt

I'm trying to use requests to request this file, write the content of it to disk in the current working directory where it can be used later. Right now, I'm using the following code:

```
import requests
from os import getcwd

url = "https://github.com/someguy/brilliant/blob/master/somefile.txt"
directory = getcwd()
filename = directory + 'somefile.txt'
r = requests.get(url)

f = open(filename,'w')
f.write(r.content)
```

Undoubtedly ugly, and more importantly, not working. Instead of the expected text, I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--

Hello future GitHubber! I bet you're here to remove those nasty inline styles,
DRY up these templates and make 'em nice and re-usable, right?

Please, don't. https://github.com/styleguide/templates/2.0

-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Page not found &middot; GitHub</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body {
        background: #f1f1f1;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        margin: 0; }

      .container { margin: 50px auto 40px auto; width: 600px; text-align: center; }

      a { color: #4183c4; text-decoration: none; }
      a:visited { color: #4183c4 }
      a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

      h1 { letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 60px; font-size: 60px; font-weight: 100; margin: 0px; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; }
      p { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); margin: 20px 0 40px; }

      ul { list-style: none; margin: 25px 0; padding: 0; }
      li { display: table-cell; font-weight: bold; width: 1%; }
      #error-suggestions { font-size: 14px; }
      #next-steps { margin: 25px 0 50px 0;}
      #next-steps li { display: block; width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 5px 0; font-weight: normal; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
      #next-steps a { font-weight: bold; }
      .divider { border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5; border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;}

      #parallax_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
      }
      #parallax_field {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 370px;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

etc etc.

 
Content from Github, but not the content of the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should really use `os.path.join()` to combine paths. `getcwd()` does not necessarily return a directory name ending in a path separator.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The content of the file in question is *included* in the returned data. You are getting the full GitHub view of that file, not just the contents.

If you want to download *just* the file, you need to use the `Raw` link at the top of the page, which will be (for your example):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/someguy/brilliant/master/somefile.txt
```

Note the change in domain name, and the `blob/` part of the path is gone.

To demonstrate this with the `requests` GitHub repository itself:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/README.rst')
>>> 'Requests:' in r.text
True
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kennethreitz/requests/master/README.rst')
>>> 'Requests:' in r.text
True
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
>>> print r.text
Requests: HTTP for Humans
=========================


.. image:: https://travis-ci.org/kennethreitz/requests.png?branch=master
[... etc. ...]
```

Comment: if you want to access a file in a private repository, basic authentication works just fine: requests.get('https://raw.github.com/myfile.txt', auth=('username', 'passwd'))

Comment: arg, the code snippet got messed up, here again: `requests.get('https://raw.github.com/myfile.txt', auth=('username', 'passwd'))`

Comment: just a note that the raw link is served with cache time for 5 mins. so a change to the file will reflect in the raw link after mins.

Answer (score 15):

You need to request the raw version of the file, from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`.

See the difference:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/django/django/master/setup.py vs. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/setup.py

Also, you should probably add a `/` between your directory and the filename:

```
>>> getcwd()+'foo.txt'
'/Users/burhanfoo.txt'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join(getcwd(),'foo.txt')
'/Users/burhan/foo.txt'
```

Comment: This is a much simpler implementation than the accepted answer and will work perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: Wdym it's the exact same he just didn't give an example ??? lel

Answer (score 10):

Just as an update, `https://raw.github.com` [was migrated](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-04-25-user-content-security/) to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`.  So the general format is:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/branch/[subfolders]/file"
```

E.g. [`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/earnestt1234/seedir/master/setup.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/earnestt1234/seedir/master/setup.py).  Still use `requests.get(url)` as in Martijn's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a working example ready for copy+paste:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/organization/repo/branch/folder/file"

# If repo is private - we need to add a token in header:
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Authorization"] = "token TOKEN"

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
```

(*) If repo is not private - remove the headers part.

---

**Bonus:** 
Check out [this](https://reqbin.com/req/python/c-xgafmluu/convert-curl-to-python-requests) Curl < --> Python-requests online converter.