# Getting a file path from GitHub

Tags: github, google-colaboratory, arff

I have the code below in my Google colab, and it is giving me the error message:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Code:

```
!pip install arff    
import arff
uploaded = arff.load(open('https://github.com/userName/repoName/blob/combination_of_nums_and_letters/file_name.arff'))
```

I got the file path by clicking on "Copy permalink" in GitHub.

Is this an issue with the path I got? or with my code? And if the path is wrong how can I get the correct path for this code to work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Python file open only looks locally. To open a file from the internet you will need to download it using a request.
2. The link needs to be the "raw" version (put `raw.githubusercontent` instead of `github.com`) and remove the `"/blob/"` portion of it.

This question should help you: [How to download and write a file from Github using Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120502/how-to-download-and-write-a-file-from-github-using-requests)