# How to download a file from GitHub using Python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, github

I don't know if it was posted before but I could not find it neither on Stackoverflow nor on the rest of the web

I'm working on a project where we need **a live dataset** so we can update our database everyday. I found [**a GitHub repository**](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data) where a csv file is updated everyday and I need to download it to my local as I run a code. How am I supposed to do that ?

*We are using Python and PostgreSQL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the path of your desidered csv (`raw format`):

```
csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/latest/owid-covid-latest.csv'
```

Then read it in python with :

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_url, error_bad_lines=False)
print(df)
```

You can now update your sql db with:

```
df.to_sql('my_SQL_table', con=my_engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: why to use panadas?

Comment: OP says  "so we can update our database everyday"....  Importing a csv with pandas (as df) will let you  to easily use  `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql ` to manage a  sql update.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer for your question, check this link below:
[How to download a file from Github using Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120502/how-to-download-and-write-a-file-from-github-using-requests)

> If you want to download just the file, you need to use the Raw link at
> the top of the page, which will be (for your example):
>
> `https://raw.github.com/someguy/brilliant/master/somefile.txt`
> Note the change in domain name, and the `blob/` part of the path is gone.

Try this code to download the `COVID-2019 20-20ECDC 20(2020).csv` file:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/ecdc/COVID-2019%20-%20ECDC%20(2020).csv')
>>> 'Requests:' in r.text
True
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> r = requests.get('https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/ecdc/COVID-2019%20-%20ECDC%20(2020).csv')
>>> 'Requests:' in r.text
True
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automate this by using the request library and downloading the CSV file using the link to the file from github. As long as its file that it is the file that is being updated every time this runs it should be the most recent data.

```
import requests

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('data.csv', 'wb').write(r.content)
```