# Download a file from a GitHub repository using Python

Tags: python, download, extract

I would like to download a single file from a GitHub repository. In bash, you could do something like this:

```bash
curl -kLSs "https://github.com/mikolalysenko/lena/archive/master.tar.gz" | tar xz --wildcards '*lena.png' --strip-components=1`
```

to download and save [this file](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/lena/blob/master/lena.png) in the current working directory. How would one do this using only Python (aka. not calling a bash command)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if with "pure python" you mean without modules, if not using the method [`urlretrive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) from the `urllib` module could be a solution:

```py
import urllib.request


def main():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikolalysenko/lena/master/lena.png", "test.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To download files from github you have to use the `raw.githubusercontent.com` domain, because the files of github repositories get stored there, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065921/what-do-raw-githubusercontent-com-urls-represent) explains it better.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of [How to download and write a file from Github using Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120502/how-to-download-and-write-a-file-from-github-using-requests)

But if you want to avoid using external modules, the following code can work:

```py
import urllib.request

url = ""
file_name = "file_name"

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as file, open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(file.read().decode())
```

You can change `open` function parameters to save the file in your desired place

Answer (score 0):

I use this do download the zip embedded `changlog.txt` file from a project I follow on github.

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile


file_name = 'lena.png'
timeout = 10
url = 'https://github.com/mikolalysenko/lena/archive/master.zip'

r = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
if r.ok:
    print('found:', Path(url).name)
    with ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content)) as f:
        for file in f.namelist():
            if file.endswith(file_name):
                print('found:', file)
                data = f.read(file)
                Path(Path(file).name).write_bytes(data)
else:
    print(r)
    print(r.text)
```