# Updating timestamp from Github Repo: KeyError: 'signed' & "tuf.api.serialization.DeserializationError: Failed to deserialize JSON"

Tags: tuf, tufup

I'm just trying to get my hands around a simple version of updating  an app that I have its repo targets & metadata hosted on a separate Github repo.  **I got it working great when locally hosted per the tufup_example guide...** The issue I'm running into is that whenever I start main.exe (created by following tufup_example on windows) is that (I think) the timestamp.json isn't correctly being deserialized...

I've ran through tuf's & tufup's docs and have been at this for a week,  so now I'm earnestly asking for help or guidance on this.  Am I overlooking something? Do I need to do something special to sign metadata now that it's hosted on Github?

Copy of my error is below,  I hope it's just something simple I'm overlooking:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "myapp\__init__.py", line 75, in main
  File "myapp\__init__.py", line 36, in update
  File "tufup\client.py", line 154, in check_for_updates
  File "tuf\ngclient\updater.py", line 133, in refresh
  File "tuf\ngclient\updater.py", line 346, in _load_timestamp
  File "tuf\ngclient\_internal\trusted_metadata_set.py", line 211, in update_timestamp
  File "tuf\api\metadata.py", line 263, in from_bytes
  File "tuf\api\serialization\json.py", line 40, in deserialize
tuf.api.serialization.DeserializationError: Failed to deserialize JSON
[11720] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
PS C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\my_app> .\main.exe
INFO:__main__:my_app 1.0
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient._internal.trusted_metadata_set:Updating initial trusted root
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient._internal.trusted_metadata_set:Loaded trusted root v1
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient.fetcher:Downloading: https://github.com/username/updater/blob/main/metadata/2.root.json
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient._internal.requests_fetcher:Made new session ('https', 'github.com')
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): github.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://github.com:443 "GET /username/updater/blob/main/metadata/2.root.json HTTP/1.1" 404 None
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient._internal.trusted_metadata_set:Updated timestamp v3
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient.fetcher:Downloading: https://github.com/username/updater/blob/main/metadata/timestamp.json
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient._internal.requests_fetcher:Reusing session ('https', 'github.com')
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: github.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://github.com:443 "GET /username/updater/blob/main/metadata/timestamp.json HTTP/1.1" 200 2321
DEBUG:tuf.ngclient.fetcher:Downloaded 6205 out of 16384 bytes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tuf\api\serialization\json.py", line 37, in deserialize
  File "tuf\api\metadata.py", line 172, in from_dict
KeyError: 'signed'
```

I created a working app that would auto-update itself from a localhost server as described in the tufup_example,  however when I created a new repo from github and hosted fresh files that had the metadata and target files pointing to that Github repo,  I received the above error(s).

I tried creating several "clean" repos and clients but have not been able to figure out this error.

Answer (score 1):

When the app checks for updates and `JSONDeserializer.deserialize()` is called for the `timestamp.json` file, the raw data is the entire Github webpage, so using [this stack overflow post about using https://raw.githubusercontent.com rather than github.com...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120502/how-to-download-and-write-a-file-from-github-using-requests/14120601#14120601), this grabbed solely the contents of the JSON file, *rather than* a response containing it and other elements of the page!

Using the `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/` address path makes the app run successfully in its production env.